# How to use mtrace for server

Tags: c++, linux, mtrace

I successfully used `mtrace()` in my program, but it only created an unreadable file of 16MB, I read [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Interpreting-the-traces.html#Interpreting-the-traces) that to create a readable file I should use:

```
 mtrace ./myexe log
```

the problem is that I have a Server which requires some arguments and I have to run an application on it too, I tried running this:

```
 mtrace "./Server args" log
```

but instead if opening the server and waiting for the application, it just outputted a list of non freed memory.

So my question is how do I use `mtrace` for servers correctly?

**EDIT:**

running mtrace with the unreadable file give me this:

```
 mtrace "./Server args" log
```

a lot of lines like this:

```
- 0x0000000003941d40 Free 224404 was never alloc'd 0x2384d8b
```

and this:

```
Memory not freed:
-----------------
           Address     Size     Caller
0x00000000039600f0     0x48  at 0x238766c
0x00000000039739e0     0x38  at 0x37f0c0cbad
0x00007fc398000960     0x75  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3980009e0     0x30  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c0001240     0x26  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c00012a0     0x27  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c0001ee0     0x29  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c0001f20     0x2a  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c0001f90     0x2a  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c0001fd0     0x22  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c0002030     0x2a  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c00026c0     0x29  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c0002700     0x22  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c0002730     0x29  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c00032d0     0x26  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c00034d0     0x27  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c00035b0     0x22  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c00035e0     0x29  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c00082b0      0x9  at 0x37f1081182
0x00007fc3c00084b0     0x28  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c000a2f0      0xb  at 0x37f1081182
0x00007fc3c000a650     0x26  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c000ac10     0x1e  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c000af90      0xc  at 0x37f1081182
0x00007fc3c000b360     0x29  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c000b870     0x38  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c000ede0      0xc  at 0x37f1081182
0x00007fc3c00118a0     0x22  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c0011f30     0x2c  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c0011fd0     0x1e  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c0012040     0x2a  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c0012c30     0x40  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c0014700      0xb  at 0x37f1081182
0x00007fc3c0014f10      0xb  at 0x37f1081182
0x00007fc3c0014fa0      0xb  at 0x37f1081182
0x00007fc3c00151d0     0x88  at 0x7fc3f7cc05c9
0x00007fc3c001d4b0     0x88  at 0x7fc3f7cc05c9
0x00007fc3c0024a00      0xb  at 0x37f1081182
0x00007fc3c003e960     0x40  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c003edb0     0x88  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c003ee40    0x170  at 0x37f0c118a3
0x00007fc3c003efc0     0x88  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c003f050    0x170  at 0x37f0c118a3
0x00007fc3c003f1d0     0x88  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c003f260    0x170  at 0x37f0c118a3
0x00007fc3c003f3e0     0x88  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c003f470    0x170  at 0x37f0c118a3
0x00007fc3c003f5f0     0x88  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c003f680    0x170  at 0x37f0c118a3
0x00007fc3c003f800     0x88  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
0x00007fc3c003f890    0x170  at 0x37f0c118a3
0x00007fc3c0040890        0  at 0x7fc3efa7ee9d
0x00007fc3c00408b0      0x8  at 0x7fc3efa7ee9d
0x00007fc3c0040fc0    0x3f0  at 0x7fc3f3f0b2fd
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the use of the mtrace command. Based on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mtrace#MTrace_Usage) it seems that mtrace merely converts the logfile into something human readable. To create the logfile in the first place you need to run the application.

So to *create* a logfile you first put the relevant calls to `mtrace()` (the c function) etc. into your code and recompile with debugging enabled. Next you simply run the program as normal:

```
./Server args
```

which will write any memory issues to a logfile whose name is set by the `MALLOC_TRACE` environment variable.

Then to *read* the logfile you run

```
mtrace Server <logfilename>
```

edit: For general debugging of memory problems I would recommend looking into valgrind instead (unless of course you already know about valgrind and have a good reason not to use it for this case).

Comment: i did as you said, but it gave me an output I cant read, see EDIT (and since it said i should get a readable file, i think its not what i'm looking for)

Comment: I see that it should work, but I do have my executable compiled without optimization and -g, but i still get unreadable file.

Comment: Did you run `mtrace "./Server args" log` or `mtrace ./Server log`? I think the second one is what you need to use (it needs the binary to extract information about what the memory addresses mean, but it doesn't need the command line arguments to do that).